# Exctracting Curl from postman not working

Tags: curl, postman

I Exctract Curl from postman, but not working as following :

```
curl --insecure --location --request POST "https://172.25.128.114/api/iban/term/list " --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Forwarded-For: 81.12.112.243' --header 'Authorization: Basic a2FzaGVmdXNlcjpFbmVhbWlAMTIzNDU=' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=B10D83AE3D70741D637BA3C2E3F1FB24' --data-raw '{ "iban":"IR220540202902540062587008","page" : 1 }'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Does this request work in postman? 401 generaly means you are using an invalid token or authenitcation method ...

Comment: yes it works. I extract it from postman

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Cookie from the request? Did you specifically add that to the original request or was it part of the response?

Comment: Cookie generated from postman when export Curl.

Comment: It's generated based on you/whoever making a request , then you're getting the curl code from the code tab based on that response. If you create a fresh request, is that cookie there? Did you try it without the cookie header, if it still doesn't work - that's cool. Can you add more context of the actual request from Postman, attached an image of that.

Comment: The image from the app shows basically the same information as you've added previously. You're using a really old version of Postman there too. Version 7 maybe. Can you show the request, with the Headers in the builder.

Comment: Thanks, my problem solved after chaanging single quotation to double quotation

Comment: Looks like dropping the cookie header off the curl statement helped too, judging by the answer 

Comment: No, after removing cookie I tested, but problem exist. Also thanks miilion from you

Comment: Cool. I would suggest updating your version of the app. Looks like a couple of major versions behind. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after changing single quotation to double quotation (postman generate wrong curl by single quotation)

```
curl -k --location --request POST "https://172.25.128.114/api/iban/term/list " --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Forwarded-For: 81.12.112.243" --header "Authorization: Basic a2FzaGVmdXNlcjpFbmVhbWlAMTIzNDU=" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{ "iban":"IR220540202902540062587008","page" : 1 }"
```